# Deprecation Warning Python

Tags: python, deprecation-warning, minmax

Does anybody know how can i solve this warning in the code below?

Here is the warning:
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  warnings.warn(DEPRECATION_MSG_1D, DeprecationWarning)

Here is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats, integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import seaborn as sns

data = np.genfromtxt('name.csv', delimiter=",")
X = data[:,1]
mms = MinMaxScaler()
a=X.reshape(-1, 1)
a_norm = mms.fit_transform(X)
sns.set(color_codes=True)
np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, "distributions")))
sns.distplot(a_norm);
```

Even though, I am making changes according to the warning, I am getting the error which is mentioned above from this line 
"a_norm = mms.fit_transform(X)".

I really need help for this warning

Comment: You seem to call `X.reshape`, save the result into a variable called `a` which you then never reference for the rest of the script. I suspect you mean to pass `a` instead of `X` to which function is throwing that deprecation warning?

Comment: @shadow I wanted to see distribution of data after normalization which is stored in "a_norm". So, I have a_norm for the parameter of sns.distplot(). In fact, mms. fit_transform is giving me the error.

Comment: What about `a_norm = mms.fit_transform(X)`? Shouldn't that be `a_norm = mms.fit_transform(a)`?

Answer (score 0):

replace `a_norm = mms.fit_transform(X)` with `a_norm = mms.fit_transform(a)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18346180)

Comment: Actually i just received the privilege to comment ... I am sorry ... I am a newbie... Still learning the rules